# complex mongoid rails model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid

I am using devise as the user management system and planning to use CanCan for more advanced permission settings.

I want to build a regional discussion board,I have the follwing models

- User model
- City model
- Talk model

every registered user can create a city and then a temporary edit permission will be given, however the admins controls everything and can revoke the permission of the one who created the city.  As for the Talk model, users can only create or delete messages using ajax.

E.g. http://localhost:3000/nyc/ ==> to list all talk messages

http://localhost:3000/nyc/new ==> to create talk messages

How can I relate all these relationships via mongoid?
And How do I set the routes.rb file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use add association between your city and talk like that :

```
Class City 
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :talks
end

class Talk

  include Mongoid:Document

  belongs_to :city
end
```

See the documentation about relation on mongoid : http://mongoid.org/docs/relations.html

Comment: first of all, thank you for answering my question, can you tell me how to relate the user model to those two models? What I want to ask is whether the user model can have many cities and talks at the same time.

Comment: You can link by `belongs_to` `has_many` from `User` to your `Talk` or `City`. But depend what type or request you want to do and how you need implement it. MongoDB has no join system. So you need to 1 request by collection you have to get information. If you link user to City contains some Talk, you need do 3 request to have all talk of your user. You can associate talk to user. But you need maintain the list yourself. After it's more about validation than other.